# Why are two equal variables not considered equal?

Tags: python, if-statement

When programming something in python I came across this bug where 2 variables that are certainly equal don't count as equal when put through an if `X == Y`:

Relevant segment of code:

```
 usernameinput = input("Enter your username: ")
    print("Just a sec...")
    passwordinput = hashingAlgorithm2()
    for line in Database:
        IDNumber, Username, Password = line.split(",")
        if Username == usernameinput:
            print(passwordinput)
            print(Password)
            if passwordinput == Password:            (this is the line in question)
                print("Test")
                LoggedIn = True
                ID = IDNumber
    if LoggedIn == False:
        triesLeft = triesLeft - 1
        print("Your username or password is wrong, you have", triesLeft ,"tries left.")
        if triesLeft <= 0:
            The_Correct_Password
```

Relevant results:

```
Enter your username: daniel
Just a sec...
Enter your password: **********
12894487843593301576106844
12894487843593301576106844

Your username or password is wrong, you have 2 tries left.
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

I have no clue as to what even is the problem, as both variables are shown to be equal at the time of the if `X == Y`

Comment: What happens if you look at the `repr`s of both items?

Comment: "_are certainly equal_" Hmm... can you confirm this? Perhaps they're of different types (e.g. one might be an int, another might be a string). Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: *"certainly equal"* is a belief. To confirm, print values with their *type* before you do the check. I bet you will be surprised.

Comment: my guess is that you have a 'newline' at the end of the second password. Try doing passwordinput.strip() == Password.strip()

Comment: It seems that your second password has a `\n` char at the end. Indeed, your second print command write the password and skip a line. Try to remove this `EOL` char

Comment: Austin, in the results, the two values are printed, they're the numbers.

Comment: @D.Cronin just because a variable *prints* as a number doesn't necessary mean it *is* a number behind the scenes. `print('1')` and `print(1)` both output `1`.

Comment: Remember a string and an int are not the same because they have different types so 1234 == '1234' will result in false.

Comment: I just realized that reading the integer back out from the file made it back into a string, which _looked_ the same but was actually different. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue by casting Password to an `int` (assuming your hash function always returns an `int`).

```
   usernameinput = input("Enter your username: ")
   print("Just a sec...")
   passwordinput = hashingAlgorithm2()
   for line in Database:
       IDNumber, Username, Password = line.split(",")
       if Username == usernameinput:
           print(passwordinput)
           print(Password)
           if passwordinput == int(Password):  # Change here          
               print("Test")
               LoggedIn = True
               ID = IDNumber
   if LoggedIn is False:
       triesLeft = triesLeft - 1
       print("Your username or password is wrong, you have", triesLeft ,"tries left.")
       if triesLeft <= 0:
           The_Correct_Password
```